# Homeomorphism between intervals of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $a,b$ are any real numbers, prove that the following intervals are homeomorphic: $$ (-\infty,a]\cong (-\infty,b] \cong [a,\infty)\cong [b, \infty) $$

To prove that $[a, \infty) \cong [b, \infty)$ I thought of the line through the points $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ with $a <c$ and $b <d$, in a similar way to prove that $(- \infty, a] \cong (- \infty, b]$ take the line through the points $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ with $a>c$ and $d> b$. These functions are correct and in the case of $ (-\infty, a]\cong [a, \infty)$ as could be the function.

Comment: Hint: Think reflection and translation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(-\infty,a]$, $ B= (-\infty,b]$, $C= [a,\infty)$, $D= [b, \infty) $, $E=[0,\infty)$.

Let $f_A\colon A\rightarrow E$ be given by $F_A(x)=-x+a$

Let $f_B\colon B\rightarrow E$ be given by $F_B(x)=-x+b$

Let $f_C\colon C\rightarrow E$ be given by $F_C(x)=x-a$

Let $f_D\colon D\rightarrow E$ be given by $F_D(x)=x-b$

I'll let you show that these are continuous maps with inverses and then, using the fact that homeomorphism is an equivalence relation, you can easily get the chain of equivalences in your question.